# Context variables on several templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a `view`, which return context {}. I need to use these context variables not in one `template.html`, - but in several templates. **How can I do this?**

```
return render(request, 'cart/cart_detail.html', {
                                           'order':order,
                                           'order_item':order_item,
                                           'total':total}
```

Comment: Are you willing to use class-based views? Or just function-based views?

Comment: @Jarad just function views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you could use context processors, that's what i use to get my conxtext inside navbar anf therfore show it in all my templates:

1 - create a context_processors.py in your app then add your function in it.

2 - in settings.py

```
        TEMPLATES = [
        {
        ...
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    ....
                    'your_app_name.context_processors.your_function_name',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

3 - use it in your templates:

```
    def your_function(request):
        // ... whatever you have or nothing
        return dict(order=order,order_item=order_item,total=total)
```

(i could forgot something, you could check the docs), hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! Tomorrow I will try your option, and if it works, I will mark it as a solution. Question: context_processors.py to create just a file or a package?